# Let $V=Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $T:V\rightarrow V$ the linear operator $T(A)=A^t$. Find the characteristic polynomial of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $T:V\rightarrow V$ the linear operator $T(A)=A^t$. Find the characteristic polynomial of $T$.

**My work:**

$(T\circ T)(A)=T(T(A))=T(A^t)=(A^t)^t=A$

$P_{T\circ T}(x)=P_A(x)=det(xI-A)$

then

$P_T(x)=P_{A^t}(x)=det(xI-A^t)$

Is correct my reasoning? Can someone help me? thanks!

Comment: This would mean that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ depends on $A$, which cannot be the case. The characteristic polynomial of $T$ must have degree equal to the dimension of the vector space on which the transformation acts, i.e. degree $n^2$. On the other hand, $T \circ T - Id = 0$. What does that say about the minimal polynomial of $T$?

Comment: if $T\circ T -Idv =0$ then the minimal polynomial is $T\circ T -Idv$ no?

Comment: These last few days we've had a ton on questions on the eigennvalues be of transpositions and so on... Clearly,no one bothers to search anything before asking. Sigh.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, $T$ is a symmetry ($T\circ T=Id$), then its characteristic polynomial is 
$$
(X-1)^{d_{i}}(X+1)^{d_{ai}}
$$
where $d_{i}$ (resp. $d_{ai}$) is the dimension of the invariant (resp. antiinvariant space). Using the matrix units $(E_{ij})_{1\leq i,j,\leq n}$, you can build bases of these spaces.

For the invariant space (symmetric matrices), one has 
$$
(E_{ij}+E_{ji})_{1\leq i\leq j,\leq n}
$$
hence $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ matrices and, similarly, for the anti-invariant space (antisymmetric matrices), one has 
$$
(E_{ij}-E_{ji})_{1\leq i< j,\leq n}
$$
hence $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ matrices.
the desired polynoomial is then
$$
(X-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}(X+1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}
$$

Hope this helps.